# How to change value of variable in $scope on-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to change the value of `$scope.complete` to `false` when the user clicks a particular URL. Is this possible to do in Angular?

I show credit card form to the user based on this variable. On first page load the variable is true/false based on value coming from server side that suggests whether there is a credit card on file or not.

If there is a credit card on file then I want to have a `change` url. Which, when clicked, would change the value of `$scope.complete` to false and the credit card form would show up.

This is my code at the moment:

JS

```
  $scope.complete = false;
  djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data){
    $scope.model = data;
    if ($scope.model.profile.stripe_id.length <= 0)
      $scope.complete = false;
    else
      $scope.complete = true;
  });
```

html:

```
<div ng-if="complete == false">
 <!--show form-->
</div>
<div ng-if="complete == true">
 Credit card already on file. <a href="#">Change?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Because ``ng-click`` is one of the basic directives. Most tutorials use it in their examples.

Comment: What do you mean by "user clicks a particular URL"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a function to ng-cick and have the function change the value of the property:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.complete = true;

    $scope.change = function() {
      $scope.complete = false;
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-show="complete == false">
        form here
    </div>
    <div ng-show="complete == true">
         Credit card already on file. <a href="#" ng-click="change()">Change?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You actually don't even need a function.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle showing ng-click on archive()

http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM

```
  <a href="" ng-click="archive()">archive</a>

  $scope.archive = function() {
    var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
    $scope.todos = [];
    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
      if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
    });
  };
```

This isn't my fiddle, but shows how to use it.

Documentation is also at:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
$scope.complete = false;
  djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data){
    $scope.model = data;
    // default scope
    $scope.complete = true;
    $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.complete = true;
    }
    if ($scope.model.profile.stripe_id.length <= 0)
      $scope.complete = false;
    else
      $scope.complete = true;

  });
```

html:

```
<div ng-if="complete == false">
 <!--show form-->
</div>
<div ng-if="complete == true">
 Credit card already on file. <a ng-click="change()" ng-href="#">Change?</a>
</div>
```